# React-table - disable global filter for one column, but add another filter for disabled one

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Is it possible to disable global filter for one column, but add another filter for disabled one in the `react-table` ?
Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution, in case if someone need this:

```
     {
            Header: 'Age',
            accessor: 'age',
            Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
            filter: 'equals',
            disableGlobalFilter: true,
          },
```

Comment: That `disableGlobalFilter` was breaking my head... Thanks!

Comment: @Sonhja happy to help!